# .htaccess seo rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

my current setup is:

```
site.com/DIR/56
```

what I want to do is:

```
site.com/DIR/56/some-string-here-about-the-page
```

my current .htaccess setup is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteRule ([0-9]+) index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: You accept *any* numerals. So it should already work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an .htaccess expert, but it seems to me your existing setup will work.  What it is doing is taking the uri given and finding an integer inside it -- anywhere inside it.  It then ignores all the other text in the uri, by rewriting it as index?id=$1.  $1 is simply the integer found, for example, 56.

You could be more explicit and try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteRule DIR\/([0-9]+)(\/)? index.php?id=$1
```

However, I'm reasonably sure your fancy-urls will work correctly without any change.